# javascript Array List Filter Not Working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a web service and this service returns json data.
Example :

```
{
     "id": -65000,
     "name": "SIK KULLANILANLAR",
     "stockCode": null,
     "groupId": 200000,
     "price": 0.0,
     "color": null,
     "type": 1,
     "mustModGrpCount": 0,
     "mustModGroups": "0",
     "order": 0,
     "campCount": 0,
     "populer": false
 }, {
     "id": 3882,
     "name": "MILLER",
     "stockCode": "ALK001",
     "groupId": 200042,
     "price": 8.9,
     "color": "aliceblue",
     "type": 3,
     "mustModGrpCount": 0,
     "mustModGroups": "",
     "order": 0,
     "campCount": 0,
     "populer": false
 }, {
     "id": 3883,
     "name": "EFES PILSEN 33 CL",
     "stockCode": "ALK002",
     "groupId": 200042,
     "price": 7.9,
     "color": "aliceblue",
     "type": 3,
     "mustModGrpCount": 0,
     "mustModGroups": "",
     "order": 0,
     "campCount": 0,
     "populer": false
 }
```

I'm filtering this data for `groupId` and it works. But I tried the filter for `populer` field and it's not working.  I guess because of variable type: `populer` returning boolean.

this is working :

```
NewMobile.globals.products.filter('groupId',200000);
```

but this is not working

```
NewMobile.globals.products.filter("populer",true);
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: it is just a part of data for example

Comment: So, what is `NewMobile.globals.products.filter`

Comment: NewMobile.globals.products is a object. json data stored here

Comment: And what does its `filter` method do?

Comment: I am request the all products to NewMobile.globals.products. And filter method filtering the values. exp: products.filter("fieldname","filtering value");

And it is just showing filtered values.

Comment: Are you filtering a store or an array? Because if `NewMobile.globals.products.filter('groupId',200000);` works, it is definitely a store...

Comment: NewMobile.globals.products is variable. im filtering this variable and sending data to a store.

Comment: Could you please try this:
`NewMobile.globals.products.filter([{filterFn: function(record) { return record.get("populer") === true; }}]);`

Comment: @Akori no, it is not worked. thanks for answer..

Comment: I really wish I knew what object you are using, because it isn't a store nor an array, but you are definitely using an ExtJS object, otherwise Igor's attempt would work, so could you please provide the xType?

Comment: @Akori i wrote my code in answer.

Comment: @cptc what does your Model look like? I suspect that you have `{name: 'populer', type: 'auto'}` when you should have `{name: 'populer', type: 'boolean'}`

Comment: @Niederee Yes populer field type is boolean {name: 'populer', type: 'boolean'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I run project , this old code adding a new filter.

NewMobile.globals.products.clearFilter(); I used this and problem solved. 
 clearFilter is clearing old filters.
Thanks for your all suggestions and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

If the **NewMobile.globals.products** is a standard array then the filter method attached to the Array object should be done like this:

```
NewMobile.globals.products.filter(function(el) { return el.populer === true; })
```

Because the filter function takes a function, not a field, as its argument.

You can read the MDN documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: thanks for answer but  i saw this link  before and i tried but not worked. your code too..

Comment: Maybe you have some problems with the browser, the filter method is relatively new and not supported everywhere

Comment: NewMobile.globals.products.filter('groupId',200000); but this is working ?

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of custom filter function :/, you can always check this by typing **NewMobile.globals.products.filter === Array.prototype.filter**

Comment: @Igor, I suspect he might be using the filter function of the store: `filter( [filters], [value] )`

Answer (score 0):

@Akori

```
NewMobile.globals = {
    mesaj: 'selam',
    action: '',
    server: '192.168.50.70',
    branchCode: '0',
    activeTable: '',
    activeFolio: '0',
    activeTableGroup: '',
    activeMustGroup: -1,
    activePid: 0,
    activeMustGroupString: 0,
    activeMustDesc: '',
    activeMustArray: [],
    activeCampProduct: '',
    products: undefined,
    rePrint: '',
    activePax: 1,
    uuid: 'tanimsiz',
    activeSkin: 'Krem'
};
```

this is  launch function variable.

this my request

```
NewMobile.globals.products = Ext.create('NewMobile.store.PorductStore');
NewMobile.globals.products.setProxy({url: "http://" + NewMobile.globals.server + ':1002/zulu/newmobile/data.aspx?act=getAllProducts'});
NewMobile.globals.products.getProxy();
NewMobile.globals.products.load(function(a, records, c, d, e){
    if (c !== true) {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
        Ext.Msg.alert('uyarı', NewMobile.message.connectionError, Ext.emptyFn);

        return;
    }

});
```